# Why isn't this toggling?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get #content to toggle, but it won't work.

```
        $("button").click(function () {
      $("#content").slideToggle("slow");
    });


        <div id="container">
<button>toggggle</button>


          <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

           <div id="content">
```

Comment: Can we get the full text of your code? Or at least the full text of the pieces that matter? For example, did you include the jQuery library? Is your Javascript in <script> tags?

Comment: **It won't work** just doesn't help us to know the problem cause. Explain better and if possible create a jsFiddle for this.

Comment: It's enclosed in script tags. The problem is that when I click on the button, nothing toggles..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works:

http://jsfiddle.net/NRj3K/

Something must be wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Is the jQuery code before the html code? Then it will not work, since the div element will be missing when it is executed while page is loaded.

Move the jQuery code  below the `<div id="content">`

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine. check your jquery is correctly loaded.. i have check this code on jsFiddle and it is working well.

try to put this code in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function () {
          $("#content").slideToggle("slow");
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a Wordpress site with the `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` you have in there. I believe Wordpress by default uses the Prototype.js library. This is probably a conflict with the `$` object which is used by both jQuery and Prototype.js.

Look [here](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/) to resolve this. Especially suggestion 5 on the page.